# Dual Boot Windows 7 / Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows legacy

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, 20.04, windows-7

My brother gave me an old Windows 7 (legacy) in DualBoot with Ubuntu 16.10. Live-Ubuntu recognized that I already had a partition with Ubuntu on the HDD and suggested me to erase it with Ubuntu 20.04, which I accepted. The installation ended with an error about the boot module (grub2 I guess).

I tried to use the "Recommended repair" mode of boot-repair in Live-Usb mode, without success.

I mounted the drives (with the commands sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/sda2, etc.) in Live-Usb mode, and tried to use the "Recommended repair" mode of boot-repair. Even if I got further and tried to reinstall the grub2 in \dev\sda6, it ended with an error.

I generated this file => https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Cns9xWdMxn/. From this log I remark that there is a problem with my BootLoader on sdb1, and with the recognition of the several drives I have.

Here is a snapshot of my drives from Gparted:
[image: /dev/sda]
[image: /dev/sdb]

\dev\sda2 is the C drive of Windows,

\dev\sda3 contains data without importance,

\dev\sda5 contains 2 folders (BOOT and ubuntu), in which are the bootloaders. The folder "BOOT" contains BOOTX64.EFI, fbx64.efi and mmx64.efi. The folder "ubuntu" contains BOOTX64.CSV, grub.cfg, grubx64.efi, mmx64.efi and shimx64.efi,

\dev\sda6 contains the \home\user from Ubuntu,

\dev\sdb1 contains data without importance.

I am surprised to read on the log file that there is a problem with \dev\sdb1, as it contains only data.

Is there a way to fix this? As some programs are only available on windows, I would like to avoid to erase windows 7.

As written here => https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair, the Advanced options are "Not recommended for inexperienced users". I looked for a clear answer on the internet. Unfortunately I am not skilled enough and do not understand everything. Therefore I described the problem as much as possible, and I take my chances here.

Comment: This might happen if you install Ubuntu 20.04 in UEFI mode. Ensure to boot the USB installer using legacy BIOS mode, and reinstall. I have encountered a similar error when I installed Ubuntu in legacy BIOS mode on a UEFI enabled computer.

Comment: Also use gparted or Windows repair disk to move Windows boot flag back to sda1. Grub only boots working Windows & will normally boot it. But if Windows is hibernated or needs chkdsk, you either have to temporarily install Windows boot loader. After fixing Windows then restore grub to MBR of drive. Since newer UEFI system better to have UEFI, but Windows will not convert easily. Windows only boots in BIOS mode from MBR or only in UEFI mode from gpt & conversion from MBR to gpt normally erases drive. Note Windows 7 is EoL and should not be used.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi thank you, that was the right solution. I finally can start either on windows or on ubuntu. I still have to choose manually to boot on the hard disk drive to get on the grub window, but I think i will figure out how to configure that properly.

Comment: @oldfred thank you for your answer too. Indeed my plan is to retrieve the programs and the data from windows 7 and install it back on a fresh install of windows 10.

Comment: Since newer hardware, I suggest using UEFI. But how you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs for both Windows & Ubuntu. But the UEFI Windows will totally erase drive in converting to gpt, so have good backups of all data you want to keep from both Windows & Ubuntu.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Once you remove the USB installer for Ubuntu, the computer should automatically boot from the hard disk. If it does not work, you would have to change some BIOS settings.

Answer (score 3):

This might happen if you install Ubuntu 20.04 in UEFI mode, while Windows 7 was installed in legacy BIOS mode. Ensure to boot the USB installer using legacy BIOS mode, and reinstall.

I had encountered a similar error when I installed Ubuntu in legacy BIOS mode on a UEFI enabled computer, which already had Windows installed.

In case you want to install Windows 10, I suggest you first install it in UEFI mode and then install Ubuntu.